# Error can't show all comment in facebook comment

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

In https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

I using URL to comment on `http://dongcam.vn/t2525` but when i click view more comments, it can not show all comments, It's only show 1 comment, how to fix it ?

Comment: CAn you show me your code here

Answer (score 0):

Do you have moderation of comments enabled?

Also, if the comment doesn't look like a real comment I think FB may filter it.  Your url has only 9 comments (graph.facebook.com/?ids=YOUR_URL).

For my site, when someone posted a comment "yyy", it was not displayed in the public view, but I can see it when I go to moderator view.